# Finding the root node of a tree in Postgress

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I am using PostgreSQL and I have data in a table like this.

```
id    parent_id
1      NULL
2      1
3      2
4      NULL
5      4
```

I would like to get the following result.

```
id.   root_id
1      NULL
2      1
3      1
4      NULL
5      4
```

ie for each id I would like to go up the parents until I find a parent node that does not have a parent - the ultimate ancestor so to speak.

Would be much obliged for some SQL-fu that solves this.

Thanks!

Comment: See [PostgreSQL recursive select find root element from leaf.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72262628/1995738)

Comment: Thanks but that seems to answer the question for a given leaf id. I want the root node for all ids in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start from the roots and walk the tree toward the leaves:

```sql
with recursive my_tree as (
    select id, parent_id, id as root
    from my_table 
    where parent_id is null
union all
    select m.id, m.parent_id, t.root
    from my_table m
    join my_tree t on t.id = m.parent_id
) 
select id, root
from my_tree
order by id;
```

Note that according to the definition (a node is a root when it does not have a parent), the root of node 1 is 1, not null.

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f7765270ea452730e424adbd91c91bf4)